# Serializing arbitrary objects with Protobuf in Java

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers, middleware

I want to provide communication between many JVM using protobuf. Those JVM are executing a component-based middleware, hence there are arbitrary objects that I cannot anticipate because they are written by third-party developers.
The problem is that I want to free components' developer of the burden of specifying the serialization mechanism. I think this decision has some advantages:

1. There are legacy components that were written without thinking in a specific serialization mechanism (in fact, they use built-in java serialization)
2. If the channel manages the encoding/decoding of messages then you can connect any pair of components
3. It is easier to write components.

However, the only way of doing automatic serialization is using java built-in serialization, but as we all know that's very slow. So, my question is: Can we create a mechanism to, given a Java Object, build a protobuf messsage with its content that we can send to another process??

I am aware that this is not the way you should use protobuf and I can see some problems. Let me first explain how I think we can achieve my goal.

1. If an object (O) of the class (C) has never been serialized go to to step 2; otherwise, we already have a message class to serialize this class and we can go to step 7.
2. Build a proto specification using reflection on class C as the built-in serialization does.
3. Generate message class using protoc
4. Build the generated class using the java compiler.
5. Generate class on the fly using ASM for bytecode manipulation. This class will transform O into a message we can send. It will also perform the opposite transformation.
6. Save in a cache all the classes generated for objects of class C
7. Use the class generated in 5 to create a message.
8. Send the message with whatever mechanism the channel supports (i.e. sockets, shared memory)

Note 1: You can see that we are doing this on one side of the communication channel, we need to do that on both sides. I think, it is possible to send the first message using built-in serialization (use the first object to build the protobuf message) and further objects with protobuf.

Note 2: Step 5 is not required, but it is useful to avoid reflection every time you send an object.

Note 3: Protobuf is not mandatory here. I am including it because maybe it offers some tool to deal with the problem I have.

I can see that there is a lot of work to do. I can also see that maybe it won't work in some corner cases. Thus, I am wondering if there is some library already built and capable of doing that?

Comment: So, your basic question is: Did exists some library which can do the thing? Am I right?

Comment: As far as I know, sender and receiver require the same or at least compatible protobuf definitions. If the sender generates the protobuf definition "on the fly", how will the receiver get a hold of that definition?

Comment: @Bosko: The main question is that one.

Comment: @Kasoban: I can use either "[Self-describing messages][1]" or I can send the first message with built-in serialization to build the same scheme on the other side.

  [1]: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques